# Why would you approve a revision to a copy and paste quote?

Tags: discussion, editing

This edit modified the words of a direct quote, why would/should it get approved?

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/42710/5

Source

> no harmful **equipment** would occur on and around the station.

Modified to

> no harmful **incident** would occur on and around the station.

Comment: After checking the quote is the old revision, I rolled back